# Highlighting zones in a forest tree

Tags: forest

I'd like to highlight different zones of the tree with different colors, separating them with an arched line. Is there a way to do that?

The result I'd like to achieve is something along these lines:

[image]

The code of my tree is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
[CP [,phantom]
[C' 
[C]
[TP [,phantom]
[T' 
[T]
[VP [,phantom]
[V' 
[V] [,phantom]]]]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who's got a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some trickery using the `calc` library and the `fillbetween` library provided by `pgfplots`, you could do the following (this might be not the simplest way to achieve this, I assume):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
[CP,name=cp [,phantom]
[C' 
[C]
[TP,name=tp [,phantom]
[T' 
[T]
[VP,name=vp [,phantom]
[V' 
[V] [,phantom]]]]]]]
\draw[rotate=30, name path=cpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]cp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw[rotate=30, name path=tpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]tp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw[rotate=30, name path=vpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]vp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\path[rotate=30, name path=xpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]$(vp)!-1!(tp)$) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[red, opacity=0.25, intersection segments={
        of=cpbow and tpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\fill[yellow, opacity=0.25, intersection segments={
        of=tpbow and vpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\fill[green, opacity=0.25, intersection segments={
        of=vpbow and xpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation:

- I first draw three elliptical arcs that are relatively positioned to the `CP`, `TP` and `VP` nodes in the tree. I do this by naming the nodes in the tree using the `name` option provided by the `forest` package.
- I create a fourth arc relative to a node (coordinate) that is exactly as far away from VP as VP is away from TP, but in the opposite direction. This calculation can be achieved using the `calc` library and the syntax `$(vp)!-1!(tp)$`.
- I name these four arcs using `name path` and then make use of the `intersection segments` option provided by the `fillbetween` library that comes with PGFplots (and which is described in details in the [manual currently in section 5.7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)) to create fillings between them.
- I put the three fillings on the background layer, so that they don't cover the nodes.

---

A variation using shadings:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
[CP,name=cp [,phantom]
[C' 
[C]
[TP,name=tp [,phantom]
[T' 
[T]
[VP,name=vp [,phantom]
[V' 
[V] [,phantom]]]]]]]
\draw[rotate=30, name path=cpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]cp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw[rotate=30, name path=tpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]tp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw[rotate=30, name path=vpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]vp) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\path[rotate=30, name path=xpbow] ([shift={(150:2 and 0)}]$(vp)!-1!(tp)$) 
    arc[start angle=150, end angle=30, x radius=2, y radius=1];
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\shade[left color=red!25, right color=red!0, shading angle=30, intersection segments={
        of=cpbow and tpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\shade[left color=yellow!25, right color=yellow!0, shading angle=30, intersection segments={
        of=tpbow and vpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\shade[left color=green!25, right color=green!0, shading angle=30, intersection segments={
        of=vpbow and xpbow, sequence={A* -- B*[reverse]}
    }] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! This is an amazing answer!

Is there a way to make the color fillings fade into transparency? I try several tools but it seems that whenever I use something like `path fading=south` it obliterates the opacity settings, which I'd like to maintain. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: @Tom You may want to try shadings instead of fadings. See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Does the shading is upon the text?

Comment: @projetmbc The shading is on the background layer, hence below the text.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Do you know of `backgrounds` do that?

Comment: @projetmbc Sorry, I don't really understand what you are asking about. You can load the `backgrounds` library via `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and then place paths on a background layer by drawing them between `\begin{scope}[on background layer]` and `\end{scope}`. There might be other ways to do this as well.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I just want to understand how to draw A under B, when B is coded before A in the `TikZ` code.

Comment: @projetmbc Maybe consider asking a new question then. Using the `backgrounds` library as stated in the previous comment, you can do something like `\path <B> ; \begin{scope}[on background layer] \path <A> ; \end{scope}` to place A behind B.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I will play with `background`, and look at its code.